# How can the formatting of "Input-file" be changed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can we change the styling of the file upload button?
Its the normal "choose file' button but i'd like to change it to a button with a different background color

Comment: look at this http://jsfiddle.net/JJRrc/1/

Comment: Saw that. But for some reason i m not able to see the change in my code.